# How to get array value that doesn't exist in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, each generated from a string. The strings are:

```
$string1 = "#574390, #574387, #574386, #574383 (keyboard enter)
#574368, #574367, #574364, #574361, #574357, #574355, #574351, #574343, #574341 (keyboard enter)
#574381, #574379, #574377, #574375, #574374, #574373, #574372, #574371, #574369"

$string2 = "574390
574386
574383
574381
574379
574377
574375
574374
574373
574372
574371
574369
574368
574367
574364
574361
574357
574355
574351
574343
574341"
```

Then, I do this to explode each string to array:

```
$str1 = checkstring($string1);
$str2 = checkstring($string2);

function checkstring($x) {
//check whether the string has "#" in it
   if (!strstr($x, '#')) {
     $array1 = str_replace(" ", "", $x);
     $array1 = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $array1));
     return $array1;
   }
   else {
      $array2 = str_replace("\r", ", ", str_replace("#", '', $x));
      $array2 = array_unique(explode(", ", $array2), SORT_REGULAR);
      return $array2;
   }
}
```

After that, I try to find the difference between the two array:

```
$result = array_diff($str1, $str2);
print_r($result);
```

As you can see, the difference between array 1 and array 2 is that in array 1 there is `574387` but not in array 2. The result that I get from the code is this:

```
Array ( [1] => 574387 [4] => 574368 [13] => 574381 )
```

And if I switch the value between `$string1` and $string2 the result will be this:

```
Array ( [3] => 574381 [12] => 574368 )
```

I do the switching because I want to make it able to check both ways. I was wondering what's wrong with it. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `array_diff()  returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.` so when you switch, it checkes that which value of second-array not exist in first-one and that's why anser differs

Comment: Do NOT use `strstr()` to check for the existence of a substring.  The PHP manual makes this point specifically: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php  Also, if this was my project, I'd be using regex to generate the array of numbers for `array1`.

Comment: Sorry, I generally downvote questions where the answer is to copy-paste the function definition into an answer.  This means you didn't read the manual before posting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $string1, $result);
$array1 = array_unique($result[0]);
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $string2, $result);
$array2 = array_unique($result[0]);
$arrayDiff = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
print_r($arrayDiff);
```

Answer (score 6):

> [array_diff] Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

So, it only shows the elements of array1 (in your case `$str1`), which are different to the compared arrays (in your case `$str2`). That is why `574387` is not shown in the second comparison. Also, the other two differences are shown, because instead of using a comma, you use a `(keyboard enter)` in front of them in `$str1`.

If you want to see the differences from both arrays, try something like this:

```
array_merge(array_diff($str1,$str2),array_diff($str2,$str1));
```